Include action_url in Nagios notification by email?
Is there a possible way to include action_url ( of the service definition ) in the email template ?

Just tested it, and you need the $SERVICEACTIONURL$ macro but keep in mind, the macro MAY contain relative path which is expanded in web view, but no expansion happens if you use it in notification strings. The best is to use absolute urls.
